# Interpreting unintuitive fixed effects sizes in linear mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, linear

We are working on the analysis of an online behavioral experiment in which participants had to solve problems presented in two different linguistic tenses. One of them was `future simple` and the other `future perfect`. Our goal was to find out whether one tense would improve their performance on the resolution process. The linguistic tenses were administered in a between-subject design and the solutions were submitted in written text form, akin to stories describing the steps towards resolving the problem.

In our grading of the responses, we utilized the MEPS (means-end problem solving) criteria. The exact details of the grading process aren't relevant, just know that each response is given a discrete variable score (starting with 0). In addition to this, we measured the participants' general self-efficacy (`GSE`),something like general self-confidence, using the New General Self-Efficacy Scale (0-10), as well as their particular problem-solving self-efficacy (`PSSE`), i.e. their self-efficacy when it comes to solving specific problems (also 0-10). If it seems like the two efficacy scores should be correlated, that is true. However, theoretically, and empirically they remain somewhat distinct.

Anyway, our idea for the analysis was to use a "Linear mixed-effects model" with the `lme4` package in `R` in order to get at the fixed effects of the condition (`future simple` / `future perfect`) the general self-efficacy score (`GSE` in the model below) and the problem-solving self-efficacy score (`PSSE` in the model below).
Furthermore, we wanted to include two random effects: `participant` and the kind of problem (`story` in the model).

First, we checked the necessary preliminary assumptions for linear regression found [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/). We did so twice, once for the GSE and once for the PSSE. You can see the results here:

**1.** Assumptions for linearity of MEPS score and GSE:

> [image: Assumptions check for GSE]

**2.** Assumptions for linearity of MEPS score and PSSE:

> [image: Assumptions check for PSSE]

Next, we fitted the following model:

```
score.model = lmer(Score ~ factor(Condition) * GSE_median_before * PSSE_median_before +
                     (1 | Participant) + (1 | Story), data=data1)
summary(score.model)
```

The output produced is the following:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Score ~ factor(Condition) * GSE_median_before * PSSE_median_before +  
    (1 | Participant) + (1 | Story)
   Data: data1

REML criterion at convergence: 944.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0379 -0.6275 -0.0244  0.5133  3.2144 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Participant (Intercept) 2.417    1.555   
 Story       (Intercept) 1.365    1.168   
 Residual                3.262    1.806   
Number of obs: 216, groups:  Participant, 54; Story, 4

Fixed effects:
                                                        Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                                              75.6560    28.3698   2.667
factor(Condition)1                                      -59.9742    31.7200  -1.891
GSE_median_before                                        -8.9245     3.7222  -2.398
PSSE_median_before                                      -10.2048     4.2056  -2.426
factor(Condition)1:GSE_median_before                      7.4913     4.3995   1.703
factor(Condition)1:PSSE_median_before                     8.8127     4.7837   1.842
GSE_median_before:PSSE_median_before                      1.3172     0.5479   2.404
factor(Condition)1:GSE_median_before:PSSE_median_before  -1.1124     0.6581  -1.690

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) fc(C)1 GSE_m_ PSSE__ fc(C)1:GSE__ f(C)1:P GSE__:
fctr(Cndt)1  -0.894                                                 
GSE_mdn_bfr  -0.996  0.891                                          
PSSE_mdn_bf  -0.993  0.888  0.987                                   
fc(C)1:GSE__  0.843 -0.989 -0.846 -0.835                            
f(C)1:PSSE_   0.873 -0.990 -0.867 -0.879  0.975                     
GSE__:PSSE_   0.992 -0.887 -0.993 -0.996  0.840        0.876        
f(C)1:GSE__: -0.826  0.984  0.827  0.829 -0.991       -0.989  -0.833
```

Unfortunately, the fixed effects sizes are highly unintuitive. We have read in several places that the intercepts are meaningless, and are willing to accept that the reference intercept should be around *75*. However, the effect size between a change from `future simple` (reference) to `future perfect` (condition 1) seems uninterpretable at *-59.97*, seeing as the scores given to the solutions never exceeded *15* and the means being *6.8148* for the reference and *6.0926* for the other.
Where did we go wrong? Or is there something we are missing in our interpretation of the results?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-59.97 as the estimate for `factor(Condition)1` (by the way, it's usually better to convert your data to factor before fitting the model) is the expected change in the response between the two levels of `Condition` when `GSE_median_before` and `PSSE_median_before` are both zero. If zero is a value for these variables that is not plausible, then it would be a good idea to centre these variables, which should make their interpretation more intuitive.